# Changing locale in link_to depending on attribute in db i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, multilingual, rails-i18n

Ok, I am slightly confused here - and there might be a simple solutions to this problem - but I haven't figured it out over the past two hours, so I thought I might ask.

I have a blog entires in the DB which are written in two different languages (AT & EN) - the locales defined in I18n are at (german) & en (english).

Each time I create a blog entry I save the locale together with the entry. Simplified example:

```
id  |   title      |  content  |  locale
-----------------------------------------
1   |  First Blog  |  Hey, ..  |  en
2   |  Erster Blog |  Hallo, . |  at
```

etc.

So, in general I keep those two languages separated on the site - as if those were two different sites, but accessing a bloggers profile a list of most recent blogs are shown. Some of the bloggers post in German as well as English.

If the visitor is now at www.mysite.com/en - and clicks on a reference on a german blog it will error out.

In the controller I defined the following to make sure the same content cannot be accessed via two URL's:

```
@blog = Blog.friendly.find(params[:id], :conditions => ["language_id = ?", I18n.locale] )
```

So this is to make sure SEO wise I don't get penalised. (www.mysite.com/en/first-blog == www.mysite.com/at/first-blog). Currently I catch the exception in the model:

```
around_filter :catch_not_found

.... 

 def catch_not_found
  yield
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  redirect_to blogs_path, :flash => { :error => "Sorry, the Blog isn't available in your language." }
end
```

**The question is - How can I pass the locale in link_to, so that the user gets redirected to blog in the correct locale?**

Thanks

Comment: Where did you use link_to?

Comment: Off topic, but what does `at` stand for with German abbreviation?

Comment: Hi Rich, - at stands for Austria. LuiGI, I used the link_to the following way in blog view: show.html.erb: <% @relatedblogs.each do |blog| %>
       <p><%= link_to blog.title, blog_path(blog.slug), :title => "Read "+blog.title %>, <%= blog.created_at %></p>
      <% end %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some another approaches to store translated fields for your models.

First is how [Globalize](https://github.com/globalize/globalize) gem works, when you have another polymorphic model for storing translated fields

Another are using postgresql's `hstore` for storing translations as dictionary `en : 'First Blog',  at : 'Erster Blog'`. There are [also](https://github.com/robworley/hstore_translate) [some](https://github.com/heapsource/multilang-hstore) [gems](https://github.com/ademidov/hstore_translations) that help to integrate this approach.

In both approaches you have same `post_id` for all locales, so it solves problem with links/rederects

Comment: Hi MikDiet, thank you for your feedback! I know about these gems - but I find it a bit of an overhead for the requirements. I don't have the blogs ever translated. The blog in each language does develop and evolve in their very own ways. I will take a look at Globalize, however, if this is the only way to go ... :(

Comment: MikDiet - Since it is not a major issue if blogs of both languages are listed I just leave it as it is. It works for my requirements and the linking to other locale is a nice to have. But yes, if I would want it to work I'd would go down the road you suggested. Thanks again.

Comment: George, when you store all locales in one post, it does not assume you should have both language versions of your post. In fact, if someone don't want to write English version, he can. You may setup your application, when `:en` locale is chosen, posts without this locale will not be shown by `Post.all`